# Counting records per smallest netblock (interval)

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, intervals

In SQL (postgresql 8.4.x), how can I efficiently `COUNT` the number of IP records falling within the ***smallest*** netblock of possibly encompassing netblocks?  I don't want to count `10.0.0.1` under both `10/8` and `0/0`, for example.

More concretely, given:

```
-- CREATE TABLE iplog (ip INET NOT NULL, ...)
--
      ip      | ...
==============+=====
192.168.1.100 | ...
192.168.1.101 | ...
192.168.55.5  | ...
10.1.2.3      | ...

-- CREATE TABLE netblocks (nb CIDR UNIQUE NOT NULL, ...)
--
       nb      | ...
===============+======
192.168.1.0/24 | ...
192.168.0.0/16 | ...
10.0.0.0/8     | ...
0.0.0.0/0      | ...
```

How can I efficiently produce the result set:

```
       nb      | ips_logged
===============+============
192.168.1.0/24 | 2
192.168.0.0/16 | 1
10.0.0.0/8     | 1
```

Comment: I think your question and my answer would be a better fit over on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) - if you agree, are you willing to consider self-flagging for migration there? I see you already have an account...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on 8.3 - it should be fine on 8.4 as well. We need a custom aggregate because `max(cidr)` is not built-in (even though `>` is)

```
create or replace function greatest_pair(cidr, cidr) 
                  returns cidr
                  language 'sql' immutable as 
$$select greatest($1, $2);$$;

create aggregate max( basetype = cidr, 
                      sfunc = greatest_pair, 
                      stype = cidr );

select max_nb, count(*)
from ( select ip, max(nb) as max_nb 
       from netblocks n join iplog i on(i.ip << n.nb)
       group by ip ) z
group by max_nb;

     max_nb     | count
----------------+-------
 192.168.1.0/24 |     2
 10.0.0.0/8     |     1
 192.168.0.0/16 |     1
```

If you don't want the custom aggregate, you can do:

```
create or replace view v as
select ip, nb from netblocks n join iplog i on(i.ip << n.nb);

select nb, count(*)
from ( select * 
       from v o 
       where not exists ( select * 
                          from v i 
                          where i.ip=o.ip and i.nb>o.nb ) ) z
group by nb;
```

or similar using a `with` clause and no view on 8.4, but the question said **efficiently** :-)

tested with these views:

```
create or replace view iplog as
select '192.168.1.100'::inet as ip union all
select '192.168.1.101'::inet union all
select '192.168.55.5'::inet union all
select '10.1.2.3'::inet;

create or replace view netblocks as
select '192.168.1.0/24'::cidr as nb union all
select '192.168.0.0/16'::cidr union all
select '10.0.0.0/8'::cidr union all
select '0.0.0.0/0'::cidr;
```

Comment: +1 for multiple solutions, the aggregate function, and generally approaching this in a way I hadn't thought of!

Answer (score 1):

Since IPv4 addresses are essentially 4 bytes, [they can be represented as an integer](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/IP2Integer.jsp). You can make a table containing netblock_start and netblock_end (so e.g. 192.168.1.0/24 would be 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255, resp. 3232235776 to 3232235776), then count `ip >= netblock_start && ip <= netblock_end` (the IP from your log needs to be converted into the same format for this to work).

Comment: That's the way to do it, but unless the integers are stored physically in the tables it won't be effecient. Otoh, there is no solution including parsing the IPs that will be effecient.

Comment: Thanks, Piskvor, but not necessary.  The `CIDR` and `INET` types already understand that they are intervalic:  '1.2.3.4'::inet << '0.0.0.0/0'::cidr.  The question has to do with grouping only on the *smallest* encompassing interval.

Comment: @pilcrow: Ah, I'd assume it converts them to integers internally, nice.

Comment: Might be.  But to re-raise the question:  can you show me the SQL that produces the desired result set, without redundantly counting IPs which belong to more than one netblock?

Answer (score 0):

[@JackPDouglas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378123/counting-records-per-smallest-netblock-interval/4378742#4378742) is superior.  For completeness, this is the naive approach I came up with off the top of my head:

```
  SELECT nb, COUNT('X')
    FROM netblocks
    JOIN iplog
      ON ip << nb
         AND
         nb = (  SELECT nb
                   FROM netblocks
                  WHERE ip << nb
               ORDER BY nb DESC
                  LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY 1;

       nb       | count 
----------------+-------
 192.168.1.0/24 |     3
 192.168.0.0/16 |     1
 10.0.0.0/8     |     1
(3 rows)
```